# Attaching EBS Volumes in AWS Fargate

Tags: aws-fargate

After specifying the volumes in task definition I am unable to find volumes . How can I attach the Volumes to AWS fargate ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fargate task comes with 10gig of ephemeral storage. And you can additionally mount another 4gig (only). This is ephemeral too.

Refer this doc: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/AWS_Fargate.html#fargate-tasks-storage

Comment: With the new 1.4.0 AWS Task (May 2020), Fargate instances now come with 20Gio of ephemeral storage rather than 10